No wifi on Asus Vivobook (Kubuntu 24.04)
New to Kubuntu as of yesterday, on an Asus Vivobook laptop.  I have a USB wifi dongle that is recognized and allows me to connect to wifi, and after the first time I ran apt update & apt upgrade my onboard wifi was working, but after making some other changes I'm back to not having onboard wifi.  If I run lspci | grep Network I get Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b851 which I believe is my onboard wifi device, but I'm not sure where to find other information about what might be going wrong.  I've looked through a couple of other answers here including this one that seemed promising No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS but the second answer did not solve the issue, and when trying the sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms command in the first answer I'm getting E: Unable to locate package rtl8821ce-dkms and there were no instructions on adding any repository for this, so I'm not sure what to try next.  I've also tried https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 and a few similar repos but none are working.  I kinda suspect that since my onboard wifi was working before I already have drivers for it, but it just got disabled somehow and I'm not familiar enough with the system yet to know how to fix it.  Any guidance on what to try next would be appreciated!

Found the issue!  This Arch Linux forum post gave me a hint to try disabling Fast Boot/hibernation in Windows, and this solved my issue, no driver installations needed.  (And it was a nice bonus that it wasn't some setting I bunged up and then couldn't find.)  Assuming I can get Bluetooth and all the applications I need up and running, I'm excited to be joining the Kubuntu community!
The specific command that needed to be run on an administrator command prompt in Windows:
powercfg /H off
